# Pycharm scipy SVD returning error code without message

Tags: scipy, pycharm, svd

I am trying to compute the SVD of a large matrix (4799 x 53130) using Pycharm as my IDE. The following returns the exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005), but no error message is displayed. I have looked up this error code on here and people have found a mixture of things causing it. I have re-installed Pycharm and all dependencies, yet this issue persists. I have tried also using the numpy version, which returns the same error. I'm confident this problem is related to the lapack package, since both use it. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.linalg import svd
df = pd.read_pickle(r'filepath\data.pkl')
df = df.to_numpy()
svd(df)
```

I tried using df=np.ones((4799,53130)) too in case it was my data that was the problem, and this yields the same issue. It isn't the amount of RAM, my machine has 120GB and the process doesn't go near the limit.

Comment: Try to run the same program from the console and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mikko. I tried running from the console and I get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

See this thread for a discussion of the problem https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/14001

There is no solution for this yet.